# VBS file can't get source code

Tags: vbscript

I download malware loveletter.vbs, then I try to use latest version of notepad++to open it, I set ansi and all other encoding, all I get is a lot of meaningless character, but I do notice that is is a PE file at the beginning of vbs file header.

I also use windows wscript to open it, but it said can't be opened.

I want to reverse engineering the vbs file, so I need source code of this vbs file, how can I get it? thanks

Comment: .VBS file extension do not mean that the inner file format is VBS script...

Comment: so how to see the source code of my VBS file

Comment: "VBS file" is NOT equal to "file with .VBS extension"! First may have any extension (including empty). Second may be not a script (and, it seems, it's your case), and so may have not "source code".